# Disabled Button loses TextFormat

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a button with a custom textformat that I set via the setStyle method such as:

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.font = "Arial";

var button:Button = new Button();
button.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
button.label = "Click Me";
```

However when this button is disabled it loses its textFormat. Reseting the text format after disabling the button does not affect it.

What can I do to still apply the textformat to a disabled button?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could access textField of the button.

Then use [defaultTextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#defaultTextFormat) instead of [setTextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat%28%29).

```
 var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
 tf.font = "Arial";
 my_textBox.defaultTextFormat = tf;
```

---

Apparently above wont work, but this would :

```
button.setStyle("disabledTextFormat", tf);
```

Comment: defaultTextFormat is not available to buttons as far as I know. Any way to apply this to buttons?

Comment: I believe you could access the textfield as... button.textField

Comment: Buttons have a label field. I haven't been able to figure out what the textField on a button is actually used for. Setting text or applying a textFormat to it does nothing. The only way I know to change the text on a button is using the setStyle method.